# Prove that this function isn't uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

let $f:B \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x}{1-|x|}$, prove that this function isn't uniformly contínuous.

My attempt:

I have tried to get two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ that goes to zero when n goes to infty such that $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)|$ doesn't go to zero. I tried $x_n=\frac{1}{n} $ and $y_n=\frac{1}{2n}$, I tried too $x_n= \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $y_n= -\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Can you give me a tip??

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}\mapsto 
 \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: How is $f$ defined on the sphere $|x|=1$? I guess the domain is not the whole $\mathbb R^n$ ???

Comment: What is $B{}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)= \displaystyle\frac{x}{1-|x|}$, we consider $\{x_n\}=\{1+\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $\{y_n\}=\{1+\frac{1}{n^2}\}$. Evidently, $|y_n-x_n|\to 0$, as $n \to \infty$.

But
$|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|=|n^2-n| \not\to 0$, as $n\to \infty$.

The domain can't possibly be the entire real line.

Comment: Adapt this proof for $\mathbb R^n$ by taking $x_i=(1+\frac{1}{i},0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $y_i=(1+\frac{1}{i^2},0,0,\ldots,0)$